# Helm templating doesn't let me use dash in names

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am creating a helm chart for my app. In the templates directory, I have a config-map.yaml with this in it

`{{- with Values.xyz }} 
  xyz.abc-def: {{ .abc-def }} 
{{- end }}`

When I try to run helm install I get a

Error: parse error in "config-map.yaml": template:config-map.yaml:2: unexpected bad character U+002D '-' in command.

Is there a way to use dashes in the name and variable for helm?

Comment: Could you share the full (sanitized) ConfigMap? In case it helps here are examples of the structure a ConfigMap should be compiled to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

Comment: Here is a pretty old issue about this problem https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2192 that is closed, and here is my fresh issue to document this problem: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10632

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Might be worth trying using `index` method:

```
xyz.abc-def: {{ index .Values.xyz "abc-def" }}
```

looks like it's still restricted by helm to allow hyphens in variable names (as well in subchart names) and `index` is a workaround

Comment: When I try the index, it gives me "error calling index: index of untyped nil"

Comment: sorry, is `{{ index .Values "xyz" "abc-def" }}` working?

Comment: actually, it looks like your first post was correct. I made a typo.

Comment: @user1729409 typo helped me look for typos and saved a lot of time :)

Comment: it works for me only if single quotes were added `xyz.abc-def: '{{ index .Values.xyz "abc-def" }}'`

Answer (score 3):

**For future or similar questions**

I had a nested value like this in *values.yaml*:

```
gitlab-runner:
  gitlabUrl: http://192.168.49.2:31122
```

I wanted to reference it in *configmap.yaml*, in that case i used double-quotes twice:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gitlab-config
#   namespace: {{ .Release.Name }}-ns
data:
  gitlab.rb: |
    external_url '{{ index .Values "gitlab-runner" "gitlabUrl" }}'
```

Comment: Thanks, i had a same use case and it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue because the resource defined had a '-' in its name:

```
resources:
            {{- with .Values.my-value }}
```

After I removed the '-', the error disappeared:

```
resources:
            {{- with .Values.myvalue }}
```

Comment: If you remove '-' then you also rename it to the values file.