# bad character U+002D '-' in helm

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

This is my yaml file:

```
{{ if and (eq .Values.deploytest "true") (eq .Values-development.deploytest "false") }}
....
```

and i got the following error: bad character U+002D '-'
Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm templating doesn't let me use dash in names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853679/helm-templating-doesnt-let-me-use-dash-in-names)

Comment: Is `.Values-deployment` with the hyphen intentional, or should there be a `.` instead?  `.Values.deployment` would be the `deployment` item from `values.yaml` or other configuration, but with the hyphen the name wouldn't normally be defined.

Answer (score 2):

`.Values-development` is not a name helm will let you use this way.

There are a few workarounds.
You can remove the hyphen, either by just compounding the name to `.Valuesdevelopment`:

```
{{ if and (eq .Values.deploytest "true") (eq .Valuesdevelopment.deploytest "false") }}
```

or restructuring the tree to `.Values.development`:

```
{{ if and (eq .Values.deploytest "true") (eq .Values.development.deploytest "false") }}
```

or by using a lookup function such as `index`:

```
{{ $myChk := index . "Values-development" }}
{{ if and (eq .Values.deploytest "true") (eq $myChk.deploytest "false") }}
```

Typing these off the cuff; YMMV.